# Trying to sort multidimensional mutable array with one (integer) object

Tags: iphone, sorting, sdk, multidimensional-array

I have an multidimensional NSMutableArray and I want to sort it on one of the objects.  The array is created so:

```
        [NSMutableArrayName addObjectsFromArray:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:name,[NSNumber numberWithInteger:x],nil],nil]];
```

I can't find a way to sort the entire array using the value of the second object (the integer x).

Help appreciated as always.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like a good case for `sortUsingComparator:`. You use it something like this:

```
[NSMutableArrayName sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id o1, id o2){
    NSInteger a = [[o1 objectAtIndex:1] integerValue]; // Or however to extract the int from your array element
    NSInteger b = [[o2 objectAtIndex:1] integerValue];

    if (a < b) return NSOrderedAscending;
    if (a > b) return NSOrderedDescending;
    return NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

If you're targeting pre-iOS 4.0, you can accomplish much the same thing using `sortUsingFunction:context:` and putting the block content into a C-style function.

Comment: Wow.  That is really impressive and works great.  Thanks Anomie